# How to get the product of first n integers of series?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I have been given the below series, I need to calculate the product of the first n items of this series. It is working as expected for small integers, but for big integers like `int.Max` it's going into an infinite loop.

> (1+2+3), (2+3+4), (3+4+5), (4+5+6), …

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(1);

int n = int.MaxValue;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    bigInteger *= (i + 1) + (i + 2) + (i + 3);
}

Console.WriteLine(bigInteger);
```

for n = 1, the output should be 6,
for n = 2 output should be 54

I am looking for an optimized solution that works for all integers int.Min >= n <= int.Max.

Comment: Once `i` gets to about a third of `MaxValue` the sum which will be an `int` is going to overflow.  You need to convert to `Biginteger` earlier.  Like `var x = new BigInteger(i);` and then use `x` in the formula, that way you're adding 3 `BigInteger`s that will not overflow before you do the multiplication.

Comment: @juharr thank you, but is there any better solution than this? Its running very slow

Comment: You can use math to come up with a better formula.  You're just multiplying `6 * 9 * 12 * 15  * ... * 3n`.  Which is just `3 * (2*3*4*5...*n)` which is just `3 *n!`

Comment: @juharr, it should be power(3,n)* ((n+1)!), please let me know if i am wrong

Comment: Yeah, it is `3^n`

Comment: @juharr is there any way to solve without using the library methods like power and math? so that  I can use thee code logic in other languages as well

Comment: @juharr but again , this has the same issue. how to calculate factorial of large integer value?

Comment: That's when you google for an efficient factorial algorithm https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/factorial-algorithm-more-efficient-than-naive-multiplication#:~:text=The%20best%20algorithm%20that%20is,the%20factors%20are%20multiplied%20together.

Comment: For `int.Max`, the result has roughly 2*10^19 digits which is around 7.5 exabytes if you store it efficiently.

Comment: @PaulHankin that is why I’m using BigInteger here

Comment: BigInteger cannot store numbers this large. Even if you had 8 exabytes of RAM, just printing the number out with `Console.WriteLine` would take over 60000 years assuming your console can output an optimistic 10 million characters per second.

Comment: I'm saying that it's literally impossible to do what you're asking in the question. What's the underlying problem that you're solving?

Comment: @PaulHankin omg. So we can assume that, this is not a valid case in normal scenarios

Comment: Code shown can't go into infinite loop... As @PaulHankin said it may take *some time* but it is *not an infinite loop*. Since this is not really programming question but pure math I'm not sure (and not very practical either) you probably should ask on more appropriate SE site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a practical programming question but rather theoretical math question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why are you not considering this a programming question? It’s programming question which is using mathematics. And many programming questions use mathematics

Comment: Where did you get this specific problem from?  I'm guessing maybe for a Euler problem or maybe a challenge on a site like HackerRank?  Either way these problems usually want you to do a mod with a very large prime number when computing something this ridiculously large.  And then half of the solution is a math problem and once you have the efficient formula to solve it the coding is typically trivial (though sometimes you have to do some trick to make it efficient).